# i am using find plugin in ckeditor. how can set replace text as strikethrough in ckeditor

Tags: javascript, ckeditor4.x

i am using find plugins in ckeditor. when i find text and replace that text is new text. I want to find text is present in editor with strike through

i am using this code

```
var domRange = this.matchRange.toDomRange();
    //debugger;
    //console.log(domRange);

    var oldString="<s>"+pattern +"</s>";
       var stringNew=oldString+newString;
      var text = editor.document.createText( stringNew );

     console.log(text);
    if ( !isReplaceAll ) {
    var selection = editor.getSelection();
    selection.selectRanges( [ domRange ] );
    editor.fire( 'saveSnapshot' );
    }
domRange.deleteContents();
domRange.insertNode( text );
```

Comment: Do you think you could set up a small running example? That would be very helpful for everyone

Comment: suppose find text from replace button then text is replace(older text will be replaced). But i want to  kept old text as strikethrough. i done this function but i am not getting html parser.